# How can I call several variables that begin with the same letters and how can I call all variables that contain a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I need the following two codes
1) A code to select all variables that begin with "example"
2) A code to select all variables that have "true" as value for "available"

```
example1= {price:1000, size: 1000, available:true}
example2= {price:2000, size: 2000, available:false}
example3= {price:3000, size: 3000, available:true}
example4= {price:4000, size: 4000, available=true}
```

This is what I want to achieve with code one. As there are a lot of variables I need a quick way of doing it:

```
var allexampleprices=[example1.price, example2.price, example3.price, example4.price]
```

With the second code I want to get an array with all the names of the variables that contain the value "false"

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any control over what is setting those variables?  Because there's no simple way to iterate over locally defined variables .. or global ones for that matter.

Comment: What you mean with select? store them in an array, pass them to a method to evaluate them and answer true or false?

Comment: @JorgeLuisVargas Hopefully I made things clearer now

Comment: @ExplosionPills I am not sure if I understand what you mean. I define all those variables outside functions but yes, they are affected and manipulated by some other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are the exact same thing, assuming you're not in a function:

```
var myVar       = 7;
window.myVar    = 7;
window["myVar"] = 7;
```

Therefore, you can access any global variable (a variable defined outside a function) by using the window[ insertString ] method. If you wanted to search through every property on the window object to find one called example, you'd do:

```
for( var k in window ){
  if(/example/.test(k)){
    var myExample = window[k];
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

I would HIGHLY recommend against this method, though, for many reasons. To start, it's a horribly bad practice to put anything in the global scope. Variables will start colliding all over the place on big projects. Also, the window object has soooooo many properties that searching through all of them is a horrible performance drain.

Having said all of that, I've devised an example of what you should do, including the helper functions to do it:

```
var objects =
{
  example1:
  {
    price: 1000,
    size: 1000,
    available: true
  },

  example2:
  {
    price: 2000,
    size: 2000,
    available: false
  },

  example3:
  {
    price: 3000,
    size: 3000,
    available: true
  },

  example4:
  {
    price: 4000,
    size: 4000,
    available: true
  }
}

function filter(obj, comparator){
  var list = [];
  for(var k in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(k)){ // fix for IE
      if(comparator(obj[k], k, obj)) list.push(obj[k]);
    }
  }
  return list;
}

function isExample(obj, key){
  if(/^example/.test( key.toLowerCase() )) return true;
}

function isAvailable(obj){
  if(obj.available) return true;
}

/**
 * And here's how you use it
 */

var examples  = filter(objects, isExample);
var available = filter(objects, isAvailable);

var availableExample = filter(examples, isAvailable);
```

The filter function returns an array of all of the matching objects.

--- EDIT ---

You want it to say the names of the objects in the console. I'm assuming what you mean is that the console currently shows [object, object, object, object]. There are two ways to do this:

(1) Put the name in the object itself

```
example1:
{
  name: "example1",
  price: 1000,
  size: 1000,
  available: true
}
```

(2) Capture the name in the filter operation

```
var names = [];
var examples  = filter(objects, function(obj, name){
  if(/^example/.test( name.toLowerCase() )){
    names.push(name);
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(names);
```

Comment: Okay, perfect! it works and thanks for the heads-up regarding the performance drain. Can you do a small edit and add a few lines though? What code do I need so the console shows the actual names of the objects? In case of var examples for instance: [example1, example2, example3, example4]

Comment: Sure, just updated it, but I didn't test the code for method 2 so there may be typos/syntax errors (just a heads up).

Answer (score 0):

I do like below if all variables are in global scope

```
  var passedElements = [];
  for(var i = 1, l = 100 /* Maximum number of variable */ ; i < l; i++){
       if(window['example' + i]){
          var temp = window['example' + i];
          if(temp.available === true){
             passedElements.push(temp);
          }
       }/*
       else{
          // Dont break the loop here, if any variable is missing in between 
             two variables it will fail. Eg : Example1, Example3.. 2 is missing.
       }*/
  }
  console.log(passedElements);
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Brilliant, that works! Just missing something I did not clarify before. Can you add another answer with a small edit? I need the console to give me the names of the variables. In this case: [object0001, object0002, object0003]

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like follwing line is generated by some logical code:
var example1= {price:1000, size: 1000, available:true}

Why dont you simply store the vaiable names in another array that should give you the solution of Q-1.

Then you can easily travers through all of the vaiables (array) to find the vairables that have "true" as value for "available"